# Magento 1.9: How to get a list of manufactory in the current category?

Tags: magento-1.9

Magento version: 1.9

When user open a category page and list the product of this category, I want to display a list of manufactory on the product list top not in each product.
There are many manufactory, if the product of current category are not belong to some manufactory that should not be in the manufactory list.
How to get them?

Comment: is manufactory a dropdown or text attribute?

Comment: @AmitBera the manufactory is a dropdown in the backend. but i want to get  a collection with link to filter the products.